# To what value will the series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I have done a Fourier series expansion and get $$\frac{12}{\pi(2n-1)}\sin((2n-1)x)$$
How to find the value it converges at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$?
isn't it divergent?
Please show me the correct way step by step

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you get: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{12}{\pi(2n-1)}\sin((2n-1)x)?$$

Comment: Note that $2n-1$ is odd for every integer $n$. So, modulo $2\pi$, the argument $(2n-1)\pi/2$ is either $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$. What is the sine of each of these two angles?

Comment: When $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\sin((2n-1)x)=(-1)^n$, so the series is:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}$$ which is convergent.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: Oops, yes. @DanielFischer

Comment: @DanielFischer

thanks, i saw your deleted comment. Why is sin(nπ-π/2)=(-1)^n instead of -1? sin nπ=always 0? sin π/2=1? 0-1=-1?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews
hi,
Why is sin(nπ-π/2)=(-1)^n instead of -1? sin nπ=always 0? sin π/2=1? 0-1=-1?

Comment: @problematic $\sin (\alpha-\beta) = \sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta$ by the addition theorem of the sine. So $\sin(n\pi-x)=\sin (n\pi)\cos x-\cos(n\pi)\sin x$. Now $\sin(n\pi) = 0$ for all integers $n$, so $\sin (n\pi - x)=-\cos (n\pi)\sin x$. Since $\sin \frac{\pi}{2}=1$, setting $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we see $\sin \left(n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =-\cos(n\pi)$, and it remains to see that $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$. Now by the addition theorem for the cosine - $\cos (\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta$ - we have $\cos (x+\pi) = \cos\pi\cos x = -\cos x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer

i thought you quit following this and asked another question about it, thank you anyway

Answer (score -1):

$$\sin((2n-1)\frac{\pi}{2})\\n=1,2,3,...\\\sin(1\frac{\pi}{2}),\sin(5\frac{\pi}{2}),\sin(3\frac{\pi}{2}),\sin(7\frac{\pi}{2})\\\frac{12}{\pi}\sum \frac{1}{(2n-1)}\sin((2n-1)\frac{\pi}{2})=\\ \frac{12}{\pi}\sum \frac{1}{(2n-1)}(-1)^n$$

and the series converge.

Comment: and the series converge for all n (natural) . for example n=1,2,3,...  or n=2,3,4,... , n=m,m+1,m+2,... (if m is natural )